# How to identify a user without message_deliveries webhook events on Facebook Messenger?

Tags: facebook, bots, facebook-messenger, facebook-webhooks, facebook-send-api

According to Messenger Platform rules ...

> Send API requests that use user_ref from the checkbox plugin or phone_number from customer matching to identify the message recipient will no longer trigger delivery of message_reads, message_deliveries, or message_echoes events to your webhook.

Is there any other way to identify a user?